# What is the value of the property PERSEO_ORION_URL=http://orion.docker:1026/v1/updateContext in V2 Version

Tags: fiware, fiware-cep, fiware-perseo

I am configuring fiware Perso Cep and I have the value of this property for the V1 version but I am working with V2 version.

I have look for but I only found the V1 value PERSEO_ORION_URL=http://orion.docker:1026/v1/updateContext

I expect to se the correct value to this property in order Perseo Cep performs well its work.
I need the value for V2 version, but I think it is hidden

Answer (score 0):

I don't need that property.
With http://perseo-fe-ip:9090/rules, with that it works.

With this Perseo-fe is enough:
        - "PERSEO_MONGO_ENDPOINT=mongo-db:27017"
        - "PERSEO_MONGO_USER:root"
        - "PERSEO_MONGO_PASSWORD:example"
        - "PERSEO_CORE_URL=http://perseo-core:8080"
        - "PERSEO_LOG_LEVEL=debug"
        - "PERSEO_SMTP_SECURE=true"
        - "PERSEO_ORION_URL=http://orion:1026/"